# Как сделать, чтоб превью работало в Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Я использую Jetpack Compose в своем существующем проекте и проблема в том, превью не показывается, допустим я пишу так

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun test() {
    Text(text = "HELLO")
}
```

результат

[image]

**UPD**

Что забыл? Мне кажется это как то связано с тем, что я пытаюсь добавить это в уже существующий проект, так как если я создаю проект с нуля то нет проблем с отображением.

Вот кстати ошибка которую я получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не забыли, это глюк вашей студии

Comment: У меня всё в порядке, изображается текст "HELLO". Android Studio 2021.2.1 Chipmunk Patch 1.

Comment: @vitidev добавил в вопрос

Comment: @MarianD добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы превью отображалось корректно, в вашем проекте должны быть подключены следующие зависимости:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:<compose_version>"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:<compose_version>"
```

Если отсутствует последняя зависимость, то в превью будет выпадать ошибка:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter
```

Действительно, в тексте ошибки говорится об отсутствии `ComposeViewAdapter`, и он находится в [ui-tooling-1.2.1-sources.jar](https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/androidx/compose/ui/ui-tooling/1.2.1/ui-tooling-1.2.1-sources.jar)

Кроме этого, проверьте, что версия Kotlin в проекте совпадает с версией Kotlin-плагина в Android Studio.

Также рекомендую использовать последние стабильные версии библиотек: [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details), [Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose#versions), [Compose Compiler](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose#versions).

Comment: Я добавил эти зависимости, так же делал invalidate&restart но все равно тот же результат

Comment: Проверьте, что версия kotlin в проекте такая же, что и версия kotlin-плагина в android studio. Рекомендую использовать последние версии Kotlin 1.7.10, Compose 1.2.1 и Compose Compiler 1.3.0.